# Mondo DB best practice with duplicating data

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongo db in .net.

I have a media gallery results page and a media image detail view page.

My question is should i have two different documents in mongo.

One that contains all information for the results page and one that contains all the information for the media gallery details view page such as the address, username etc.

Comment: Can you provide your use cases? Data modeling in MongoDB is generally use case driven.

Comment: You may want to give the following a read as well: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/

Comment: Do you plan to store the actual image bits in the document as well? Or store just a link to the actual image file.